# MarketingCloudSdk#init has not been called in android. push notification getDevice is not returning any values

Tags: marketing-cloud, cordova, push-notification

We have implemented push notification with cordova-plugin-marketingcloudsdk few years back in our Cordova app (as per package.json the version it shows 7.1.0)

In IOS, push notification is working fine. but in android it stopped working 8 - 9 months back.

These are our app configurations

### package.json

```
cordova": "^9.0.0"
```

### Config.xml

```
<engine name="android" spec="~6.3.0" />

<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

As per our analysis by adding some logs in MCCordovaPlugin, it shows like,`MarketingCloudSdk#init has not been called`. PFB the detailed log

`V/~!MCCordova: >>>>>> initialize cordova = org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity$1@af17ff4 V/~!MCCordova: >> Inside execute >> action = registerEventsChannel V/~!MCCordova: >> handleStaticAction >> switch >> action = registerEventsChannel V/~!MCCordova: >> registerEventsChannel V/~!MCCordova: >> Inside execute >> action = isPushEnabled V/~!MCCordova: >> handleStaticAction >> switch >> action = isPushEnabled V/~!MCCordova: >> getActionHandler >> switch >> action = isPushEnabled V/~!MCCordova: >> Inside isPushEnabled V/~!MCCordova: >> MarketingCloudSdk#init has not been called V/~!MCCordova: >> Inside execute >> action = getDeviceId V/~!MCCordova: >> handleStaticAction >> switch >> action = getDeviceId V/~!MCCordova: >> getActionHandler >> switch >> action = getDeviceId V/~!MCCordova: >> Inside getDeviceID V/~!MCCordova: >> MarketingCloudSdk#init has not been called`

**Update**

```
public class MCCordovaPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
  static final String TAG = "~!MCCordova";
  private CallbackContext eventsChannel = null;
  private PluginResult cachedNotificationOpenedResult = null;
  private boolean notificationOpenedSubscribed = false;
  private static JSONObject fromMap(Map<String, String> map) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        data.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
  private static JSONArray fromCollection(Collection<String> collection) {
    JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
    if (collection != null && !collection.isEmpty()) {
      for (String s : collection) {
        data.put(s);
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
  @Override
  public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    Log.v(TAG, ">>>>>> initialize cordova = "+cordova);    handleNotificationMessage(NotificationManager.extractMessage(cordova.getActivity().getIntent()));
  }
  @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleNotificationMessage(NotificationManager.extractMessage(intent));
  }
  private void handleNotificationMessage(@Nullable NotificationMessage message) {
    if (message != null) {
      // Open from push
      PluginResult result;

      try {
        JSONObject eventArgs = new JSONObject();
        eventArgs.put("timeStamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
        JSONObject values = new JSONObject(message.payload());
        if (message.url() != null) {
          values.put("url", message.url());
        }
        switch (message.type()) {
        case OTHER:
          values.put("type", "other");
          break;
        case CLOUD_PAGE:
          values.put("type", "cloudPage");
          break;
        case OPEN_DIRECT:
          values.put("type", "openDirect");
          break;
        }
        eventArgs.put("values", values);
        eventArgs.put("type", "notificationOpened");

        result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, eventArgs);
        result.setKeepCallback(true);

        if (eventsChannel != null && notificationOpenedSubscribed) {
          eventsChannel.sendPluginResult(result);
        } else {
          cachedNotificationOpenedResult = result;
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // NO_OP
      }
    }
  }
  @Override
  public boolean execute(final String action, final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext)
      throws JSONException {
        Log.v(TAG, ">> Inside execute >> action = "+action);
    if (handleStaticAction(action, args, callbackContext)) {
      return true;
    }

    final ActionHandler handler = getActionHandler(action);

    if (handler == null) {
      Log.v(TAG, ">> Inside execute >> handler == null");
      return false;
    }

    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        if (MarketingCloudSdk.isReady()) {
          Log.v(TAG, ">> MarketingCloudSdk.isReady");
          handler.execute(MarketingCloudSdk.getInstance(), args, callbackContext);
        } else if (MarketingCloudSdk.isInitializing()) {
          Log.v(TAG, ">> MarketingCloudSdk.isInitializing");
          MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk(new MarketingCloudSdk.WhenReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void ready(@NonNull MarketingCloudSdk sdk) {
              handler.execute(sdk, args, callbackContext);
            }
          });
        } else {
          Log.v(TAG, ">> MarketingCloudSdk#init has not been called");
          callbackContext.error("MarketingCloudSdk#init has not been called");
        }
      }
    });

    return true;
  }
  private boolean handleStaticAction(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    Log.v(TAG, ">> handleStaticAction >> switch >> action = "+action);
    switch (action) {
    case "enableVerboseLogging":
      Log.v(TAG, ">> enableVerboseLogging");
      MarketingCloudSdk.setLogLevel(MCLogListener.VERBOSE);
      MarketingCloudSdk.setLogListener(new MCLogListener.AndroidLogListener());
      callbackContext.success();
      return true;
    case "disableVerboseLogging":
      Log.v(TAG, ">> disableVerboseLogging");
      MarketingCloudSdk.setLogListener(null);
      callbackContext.success();
      return true;
    case "registerEventsChannel":
      Log.v(TAG, ">> registerEventsChannel");
      registerEventsChannel(callbackContext);
      return true;
    case "subscribe":
      Log.v(TAG, ">> subscribe");
      subscribe(args, callbackContext);
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
    }
  }
  private void registerEventsChannel(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    this.eventsChannel = callbackContext;
    if (notificationOpenedSubscribed) {
       Log.v(TAG, ">> inside registerEventsChannel");
      sendCachedPushEvent(eventsChannel);
    }
  }
  private void subscribe(JSONArray args, CallbackContext context) {
    switch (args.optString(0, null)) {
    case "notificationOpened":
      notificationOpenedSubscribed = true;
      if (eventsChannel != null) {
        sendCachedPushEvent(eventsChannel);
      }
      break;
    default:
      // NO_OP
    }
  }
  private void sendCachedPushEvent(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    if (cachedNotificationOpenedResult != null) {
      Log.v(TAG, ">> inside sendCachedPushEvent");
      callbackContext.sendPluginResult(cachedNotificationOpenedResult);
      cachedNotificationOpenedResult = null;
    }
  }
  private ActionHandler getActionHandler(String action) {
    Log.v(TAG, ">> getActionHandler >> switch >> action = "+action);
    switch (action) {
    case "getSystemToken":
      return getSystemToken();
    case "isPushEnabled":
      return isPushEnabled();
    case "enablePush":
      return enabledPush();
    case "disablePush":
      return disablePush();
    case "getAttributes":
      return getAttributes();
    case "setAttribute":
      return setAttribute();
    case "clearAttribute":
      return clearAttribute();
    case "addTag":
      return addTag();
    case "removeTag":
      return removeTag();
    case "getTags":
      return getTags();
    case "getDeviceId":
      return getDeviceId();
    case "setContactKey":
      return setContactKey();
    case "getContactKey":
      return getContactKey();
    default:
      return null;
    }
  }
  private ActionHandler getContactKey() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {       callbackContext.success(sdk.getRegistrationManager().getContactKey());
      }
    };
  }
  private ActionHandler setContactKey() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        String contactKey = args.optString(0, null);
        boolean success = sdk.getRegistrationManager().edit().setContactKey(contactKey).commit();
        callbackContext.success(success ? 1 : 0);
      }
    };
  }
  private ActionHandler getTags() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        callbackContext.success(fromCollection(sdk.getRegistrationManager().getTags()));
      }
    };
  }
  private ActionHandler removeTag() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        String tag = args.optString(0, null);
        boolean success = sdk.getRegistrationManager().edit().removeTag(tag).commit();
        callbackContext.success(success ? 1 : 0);
      }
    };
  }
  private ActionHandler addTag() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        String tag = args.optString(0, null);
        boolean success = sdk.getRegistrationManager().edit().addTag(tag).commit();
        callbackContext.success(success ? 1 : 0);
      }
    };
  }
  private ActionHandler clearAttribute() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        String key = args.optString(0, null);
        boolean success = sdk.getRegistrationManager().edit().clearAttribute(key).commit();
        callbackContext.success(success ? 1 : 0);
      }
    };
  }
  private ActionHandler setAttribute() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        String key = args.optString(0, null);
        String value = args.optString(1);
        boolean success = sdk.getRegistrationManager().edit().setAttribute(key, value).commit();
        callbackContext.success(success ? 1 : 0);
      }
    };
  }
  private ActionHandler getAttributes() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        try {
          callbackContext.success(fromMap(sdk.getRegistrationManager().getAttributes()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    };
  }
  private ActionHandler disablePush() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        sdk.getPushMessageManager().disablePush();
        callbackContext.success();
      }
    };
  }
  private ActionHandler enabledPush() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        sdk.getPushMessageManager().enablePush();
        callbackContext.success();
      }
    };
  }

  private ActionHandler isPushEnabled() {
    Log.v(TAG, ">> Inside isPushEnabled");
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        Log.v(TAG, ">> ActionHandler isPushEnabled() ="+sdk.getPushMessageManager().isPushEnabled());
        callbackContext.success(sdk.getPushMessageManager().isPushEnabled() ? 1 : 0);
      }
    };
  }

  private ActionHandler getSystemToken() {
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        callbackContext.success(sdk.getPushMessageManager().getPushToken());
      }
    };
  }

  private ActionHandler getDeviceId() {
    Log.v(TAG, ">> Inside getDeviceID");
    return new ActionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        Log.v(TAG, ">> ActionHandler getDeviceId = "+sdk.getRegistrationManager().getDeviceId());
        callbackContext.success(sdk.getRegistrationManager().getDeviceId());
      }
    };
  }
  interface ActionHandler {
    void execute(MarketingCloudSdk sdk, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext);
  }
}
```

Please advise

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using?  Have you opened a case through your Salesforce Support Representative?

Comment: Bill, we have updated our post. in package. json it shows 7.1.0 and we are using getDeviceId for retrieving unique id for device. but it is not passing any value back to corodva app. Here we have posted the MCCordovaPlugin along with the post.

Comment: Any update Bill?

Comment: Open a support case please.